# Converting from Hijri to Georgian

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

How can I convert a date from Hijri (Islamic Calendar) to Georgian in Excel 2013?

Comment: Maybe this Microsoft article is still applicable to the Office 2013: [How to enter and use Hijri date in Microsoft Excel 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/871138)

Answer (score -1):

Use this formula:

```
=VALUE("a"&a1)
```